# Loading a 32-bit dll into a 32 bit process.on a 64-bit system

Tags: dll, x86, 64-bit

I have a 32-bit dll which I am trying to load into a 32-bit process on a 64 bit machine, using LoadLibrary (C++)

Using dependency walker, I am informed that among the required dlls, "Modules with different CPU types were found"

So evidently, one or more of of the many required 32-bit dlls are not being loaded in the 64-bit environment.

All works fine in the 32-bit world

How can I persuade the 64-bit system to search paths which will pick up the required 32 bit dlls?

Comment: If it is a 32-bit process (check this) then it will -- *or should* -- load 32-bit DLLs. Likewise, a 64-bit process should load 64-bit DLLs. Which DLLs, locations, and redirections?

Comment: Yes definitely a 32-bit process. Interestingly, PE architecture of the dll being loaded is i686 (compiled with some flavor of the gcc compiler and requiring the mingwm10.dll) but I am (almost) certain the MS 32-bit commmon runtime is x86. Would this matter? Regretfully I did not compile the dll being loaded.

Comment: Which DLL is it? A system DLL or ...?

Comment: It is a custom DLL from a third party, compiled with g++

Comment: Have you tried linking against the DLL instead of using `LoadLibrary`? Just wondering...